# Generalising a dot-in-circle puzzle's solution.

Tags: calculus, analysis, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, origami

### Motivation:

> **Puzzle:** Draw $\odot$ on paper without lifting your pen.

*Solution:* Start by putting your pen in the centre of the paper to create the dot. Then fold the paper such that the edge of it touches your pen tip. Draw a line outward from the dot but on the other side of the paper. With the paper up against the original side until necessary, continue to draw the outer circle.

*Could we generalise this solution using origami and calculus (e.g., continuity)?*

### The Question:

> Suppose we have a square piece of paper and a pen. Can we make precise what it means for us to draw such shapes/curves "continuously"?

Essentially, I mean: *how do we describe rigorously the simple process of drawing on folded paper without lifting the pen, allowing for unfolding?*

### Thoughts:

My guess is that we could use origami and calculus, though I don't know much about mathematical origami. My calculus is rusty. Piecewise functions might be useful.

Maybe the domain of our functions could be $[0,1]$ for simplicity.

*Fun thought:* I think  is continuous.  (For those who can't see, it's a smiley face $\ddot\smile$ inside a circle $\bigcirc$.)

Comment: How about "a finite union of curves, lines and dots" as the set of things you can draw this way?

Comment: Can you prove that that captures the idea, @BenjaminWang?